# How to derive bounds for the $n$-th term of a subsequence of $\mathbb {N} $, knowing two functions "squeezing" the number of the terms below $x$?

Tags: number-theory, inequality, asymptotics, natural-numbers

Let $ a_n $ be the $n $-th term of an infinite strictly increasing subsequence of $ \mathbb{N}$ and denote with $\nu(x)$ the number of terms smaller than or equal to $x$. Assume also $$f(x)<\nu(x)<g(x).$$ How can we find $f_1$ and $g_1$ such that $$f_1(n)<a_n<g_1(n) \ ?\tag{$\star$}$$ Obviously one could try replacing $x$ with $a_n$ in my first display, but what if that doesn't result in $(\star)$?

I'm not sure about the tags, please feel free to improve them if you think it is necessary.

Comment: What do you mean by $n$-th element of a set? Is $\mathbb{A}$ a finite set?

Comment: @Pedro True, I had forgotten that, as I'm not yet too much in set theory. Would "class of numbers" be correct?

Comment: No, I'm not worried about set-theory questions, I just want to know that you mean by $a_n$; Say, if $\mathbb{A}$ is the set of all odd numbers, is $a_n = 2n-1$ (i.e., $a_1 < a_2 < a_3 < a_4 < \ldots$)?

Comment: @Pedro Oh. Yes, exactly. And yes, $\mathbb {A}$ is infinite, I'll had that.

Comment: @Pedro: At any rate, I think I've improved the exposition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since $a_n = \min \{x : \nu(x) \geq n\}$, we have that if $f(x) > n$, then $x > a_n$ and if $g(x) < n$, then $x < a_n$. So we may define the somewhat artificial functions $f_1(x) = \sup \{x : g(x) < n\}$ and $g_1(x) = \inf \{x: f(x) > n\}$ which satisfy $f_1(x) \leq a_n \leq g_1(x)$.

If $f$ and $g$ are strictly increasing continuous functions, we can write those expressions more simply as $f_1(x) = g^{-1}(n)$ and $f_2(x) = f^{-1}(n)$.

Comment: So if the squeezing original functions are strictly increasing, $(\star)$ is given by $g^{-1}(n)<a_n<f^{-1}(n) $? And there are no more natural alternatives, I guess?

Comment: And, if $f$ and $g$ admit two inverses, like $x^2$ having $\pm\sqrt{x}$, in $(\star)$ must one choose the smallest of the inverses of $g$ and the largest of $f$?

Comment: If $f, g$ are strictly increasing, then there is only one inverse. For instance, $x \mapsto x^2$ is strictly increasing on $[0,\infty)$ (which is what interests us since $\nu(x) = 0$ for $x < 0$), and the inverse is $\sqrt{x}$.

Comment: Alright, yes. Do you think there are more natural alternatives?

Comment: I don't think there are more natural alternatives, especially not one involving, say, a sum or product of $f(n)$, $g(n)$ or $f(n+1)$ etc. In fact, I don't think there is a simple expression involving $\nu$, as the sequence $\{\nu(n)\}_{n \leq K}$ for any fixed $K$ does not provide sufficient information.